# sscanf skips capital 'N' letter

Tags: windows, stdio, scanf

I have got a strange sscanf problem with a capital letter 'N'(maybe I do not understand something correct me please):

Example 1:

```
char cBuff[128];
sscanf("GUIDNameNENE","%*[GUIDName]%127s" ,cBuff);
```

returns `cBuff:ENE`

Example 2:

```
char cBuff[128];
sscanf("GUIDNamenENE","%*[GUIDName]%127s" ,cBuff);
```

returns `cBuff:nENE`

Example 3:

```
char cBuff[128];
sscanf("GUIDNaMENE","%*[GUIDNa]%127s" ,cBuff);
```

returns `cBuff:ENE`

I have tried many other variants but still always skips capital N. 
Where is the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`%[GUIDName]` is not a weird way of quoting and matching an exact string.  It defines a set of characters that will match.  They will match in any order, and they will match repeatedly.

The longest match for the set `%[GUIDName]` in your input is `GUIDNameN`.

You could of course say `%*[G]%*[U]%*[I]%*[D]%*[N]%*[a]%*[m]%*[e]` and that would not eat any of the characters `GUIDNam`, but it would still eat multiple `e`s.

Comment: Helped, that's true it is set of character without order.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the reason it skips the capital N is because it's part of the set of characters that you ignore. The key point is that what you specify between the brackets are a set of characters to match, not in a fixed order, but rather that sscanf tries to match the longest string consisting of only the characters after the '[' up to the first matching ']'. If I recall correct.

You could try specifying the size for the set of characters to be skipped like this:

```
sscanf("GUIDNameNENE","%*8[GUIDName]%127s" ,cBuff);
```

But that will of course only work if the string always is eight characters long and if it is you could choose to just ignore the eight initial characters like this:

```
sscanf("GUIDNameNENE","%*8s%127s" ,cBuff);
```